# Windows task schedular not execution job properly?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks, admin, system-administration

I have a sql server 2008 R2 express edition . I have written a batch file which backup all of my database of the express edition. It is working fine by execution manually. I had scheduled this batch file in a task in task scheduler but the issue it is not working properly from task scheduler . Only lesser no of databases are being backup or some times it does not. I am not able to find any error in the script or task scheduler .

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule database backup with a specified user using our [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) tool. There is possibility to create backup jobs for Windows Scheduler or use its own scheduler service (full, differential and transaction log backups).